# Convert Date from DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM to date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried Converting date from (12/03/2020 05:23) to Mar 12 2020 05:23:00 in javascript format.
But not acheived. Help me with this conversion of one format to another format

Comment: Attach the code you have tried with

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are already multiple questions with that topic here on SO.

Answer (score 2):

No need to write your own date parser, you could use a library like Moment JS.

```js
const original = '12/03/2020 05:23';
const expected = 'Mar 12 2020 05:23:00';

console.log(moment(original, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm').format('MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you do not want to use a library, you will need to tokenize your date-time string. I threw together a fairly extensible timestamp parser and date formatter below.

```js
const main = () => {
  const original = '12/03/2020 05:23';
  const expected = 'Mar 12 2020 05:23:00';
  const inFrmt   = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';
  const outFrmt  = 'MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss';
  const actual   = formatDate(parseTimestamp(original, inFrmt), outFrmt);
  console.log(actual === expected);
};

const parseTimestamp = (timestamp, format) => {
  const tokens  = format.match(/(\w+)/g);
  const pattern = new RegExp(format.replace(/(\w+)/g, '(\\d+)'));
  const values  = timestamp.match(pattern).slice(1).map(v => parseInt(v, 10));
  const lookup  = tokens.reduce((r, n, i) => ({ ...r, [n]: values[i] }), {});
  return new Date(Date.UTC(
    (lookup['YYYY'] || 0),
    (lookup['MM']   || 1) - 1,
    (lookup['DD']   || 0),
    (lookup['HH']   || 0),
    (lookup['mm']   || 0),
    (lookup['ss']   || 0),
  ));
};

const formatDate = (date, format) => {
  const pad = (val, len) => ('' + val).padStart(len, '0');
  const tokens = format.match(/(\w+)/g);
  const locale = navigator.language;
  return tokens.reduce((result, token) => {
    return result.replace(token, key => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'YYYY' : return pad(date.getUTCFullYear(), key.length);
        case 'MM'   : return pad(date.getUTCMonth() + 1, key.length);
        case 'MMM'  : return date.toLocaleDateString(locale, { month: 'short' });
        case 'DD'   : return pad(date.getUTCDate(), key.length);
        case 'HH'   : return pad(date.getUTCHours(), key.length);
        case 'mm'   : return pad(date.getUTCMinutes(), key.length);
        case 'ss'   : return pad(date.getUTCSeconds(), key.length);
        default     : return key;
      }
    });
  }, format);
};

main();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```